# how to generate integer random number in fortran 90 in the range [0,5]?

Tags: random, numbers, integer, fortran

I am kind of new in the fortran proramming.
Can anyone please help me out with the solution.
i am having a problem of generating integer random number 
in the range [0,5] in fortran random number using 
random_seed and rand

Comment: `rand` is a GNU extension.  The Fortran 95 combination is `random_seed` and `random_number`.

Comment: Is a result of exactly 5 acceptable to you? Or did you mean to ask for the range [0,5) ? The suggestions below won't give you exactly the endpoint value (except possibly by rounding.)

Comment: @SteveLionel I'm not quite sure what you mean... Could you expand on that?

Comment: You used the term "[0,5]". This is "interval notation" meaning that the value can be anywhere from exactly 0 to exactly 5. On reconsideration, that perhaps is what you want. francescalus' answer below explains in more detail.

Answer (score 14):

To support the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23057399/3157076) by Alexander Vogt, I'll generalize.

The intrinsic `random_number(u)` returns a real number `u` (or an array of such) from the uniform distribution over the interval [0,1).  [That is, it includes 0 but not 1.]

To have a discrete uniform distribution on the integers {n, n+1, ..., m-1, m} carve the continuous distribution up into m+1-n equal sized chunks, mapping each chunk to an integer.  One way could be:

```
call random_number(u)
j = n + FLOOR((m+1-n)*u)  ! We want to choose one from m-n+1 integers
```

As you can see, for the initial question for {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5} this reduces to

```
call random_number(u)
j = FLOOR(6*u)            ! n=0 and m=5
```

and for the other case in your comment {-1, 0, 1}

```
call random_number(u)
j = -1 + FLOOR(3*u)       ! n=-1 and m=1
```

Of course, other transformations will be required for sets of non-contiguous integers, and one should pay attention to numerical issues.

Comment: to avoid skew due to the limited number of bits in `real` mantissa (53 for  IEEE 754 double-precision, 24 for single-precision), you might need to call `random_number` several times e.g., see [how `_randbelow(n)` is implemented via `random()` in Python](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/1dae7450c68bad498e57800387b24cb103c461fa/Lib/random.py#L243-L248)

Comment: Is it possible to generate random real number between `(0,5)`? @francescalus

Answer (score 6):

What about:

```
program rand_test
  use,intrinsic :: ISO_Fortran_env
  real(REAL32)  :: r(5)
  integer       :: i(5)

  ! call init_random_seed() would go here

  call random_number(r)

  ! Uniform distribution requires floor: Thanks to @francescalus 
  i = floor( r*6._REAL32 )

  print *, i
end program
```

Comment: Use `real :: ...` and `6.` then. But please, do yourself a favor and switch to explicit definitions!

Comment: `i = floor( r*3. ) - 1`

Comment: I don't see why not - you're just shifting the boundaries.

Comment: YA sure. one more problem is there which is with floating point error M6101:MATH. WHY DOES IT HAPPEN?

Comment: What i found that when i am deviding some integer number 580 with the number 1.97e-7, then the division is giving an negative integer number. why is it?

Comment: thans a lot for helping me out with random number..Ya i am just shifting the boundaries.Thanks