# How to generate a random integer in a range

Tags: random, fortran, fortran90, fortran95

a program I'm writing requires me to simulate the mutation of genes. If a certain instance (J) of the gene is selected for mutation, it must randomly become one of a predefined subset of alternative genes. These discrete genes are marked by the integers in the range 0 to K-1, where K equals the total number of alleles.

So basically, I need help writing the code to randomly select an integer in the range 0 to K-1 that does not equal J. Any help is greatly appreciated!

ANOTHER EDIT: Thanks for all the help so far, I've come up with the following, which ignores the requirement that i cannot equal J. However, a further problem I've encountered is that the process must be repeated multiple times, and due to the same seed being used each time the value of i is always the same. How should I go about ensuring the seed value doesn't remain the same throughout every generation? Again, any help is greatly appreciated!

```
program randtest

implicit none

  real*4        :: u(5)
  integer       :: i(5)
  integer       :: k = 4
  integer, dimension (1) :: seed = (/2817/)

  call random_seed(put=seed) 

  call random_number(u)

i = floor((k+1)*u) 

 print *, i

 end program randtest
```

Comment: You might find your answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23057213/how-to-generate-integer-random-number-in-fortran-90-in-the-range-0-5

Comment: Following the link, replace [0,5] with [0,K-2] (assuming J is in that interval).

Answer (score 2):

One can indeed use the method given in the answers to [the other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23057213/3157076), for the set {0, 1, ..., K-1}.  The complication that J (0<=J<=K-1) can be handled by rejecting J when it is sampled.

However, a better approach is to note that there are K-2 valid integers: {0, 1, ..., J-1, J+1, ..., K-1}.  So, use the method to generate an integer over {0, 1, ..., K-2} and just shift up anything that would be affected by rejecting J.

```
call random_number(u)
i = FLOOR((K-1)*u)  !this would be how I would define the range
if (i.ge.J) i=i+1
```

Comment: Thanks, so far I've come up with the following.program randtest
  
implicit none

  real*4    :: u(5)
  integer       :: i(5)
  integer  :: k = 4
  integer, dimension (1) :: seed = (/2817/)

  call random_seed(put=seed) 

  call random_number(u)

 i = floor((k+1)*u) 
 
 print *, i

 end program randtest