# How to use "if" in Fortran

Tags: if-statement, fortran

I wanted to use "if" in a program, but I don't know where is my mistake.

I wanted to  solve this problem using fortran:
x and y roll the dice a hundred times.
Each dice that shows a larger number gets one point. If the number of two dice is equal, neither of them gets points.
Write a program that randomly plays the game and determines which one gets the most points after 100 throws and wins

my code:

```
      CALL RANDOM_SEED
    
    1   x=rand()     
    
        print*,x
    
        if(x>0 .and. x<1./6)then
                                print*,"x=1"
                            elseif(x>1./6 .and. x<2./6)then
                                print*,"x=2"
                            elseif(x>2./6 .and. x<3./6)then
                                print*,"x=3"
                            elseif(x>3./6 .and. x<4./6)then
                                print*,"x=4"
                            elseif(x>4/6. .and. x<5./6)then
                                print*,"x=5"
                            elseif(x>5./6 .and. x<1)then
                                print*,"x=6"
                            endif
    
    
        y=rand()
    
        print*,y
    
        if(y>0 .and. y<1./6)then
                                print*,"y=1"
                            elseif(y>1./6 .and. y<2./6)then
                                print*,"y=2"
                            elseif(y>2./6 .and. y<3./6)then
                                print*,"y=3"
                            elseif(y>3./6 .and. y<4./6)then
                                print*,"y=4"
                            elseif(y>4/6. .and. y<5./6)then
                                print*,"y=5"
                            elseif(y>5./6 .and. y<1)then
                                print*,"y=6"
                            endif
    
    
        goto 12
      
          nx=0
        ny=0
        n=0
    
    
    12  if(x>y)then         ! here is my problem 
          nx=nx+1                       
        elseif(y>x)then                 
        ny=ny+1                         
        endif                       
    
        
        print*,"nx=",nx,"ny=",ny
      
    
        n=n+1
    
        if(n<101)goto 1
    
        pause
    
        stop
      end
```

the problem: if `x=y` I do not want to add the number 1 to `nx` or `ny` but:

[image: see this picture]

Comment: What is your program supposed to do? Unfortunately the image attached does not make it clear to me. Can you provide expected output and actual output?

Comment: `x` and `y` are probably `double` and are barely ever the same.
In your image you are comparing `5.852904E-01` to `5.558787E-01`. Of course, the former is greater `(x>y)`. You would have to compare the rounded values

Comment: More than tangentially related to your problem is [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23057213/3157076). If you deal with `x` and `y` as integers from the start then the rest just falls out.

Comment: @LinFelix After trying again I have run the program without problem.
Thanks a lot you have guided me :)